# How to show the number of values N when calculating correlation using R?

Tags: r, correlation

To calculate the correlation between two datasets, we easily use cor(x,y).In fact, I want to show the number of values N = ?  as well.
Can anyone tell me how we can do this.I am grateful to any idea.
EDIT:as per Paul Hiemstra this function did the trick:

```
     cor_withN = function(...) {
          cor_obj = cor.test(...)
           print(sprintf("N = %s", cor_obj$parameter + 2))
           return(data.frame(cor = cor_obj$estimate, N = cor_obj$parameter + 2))
                              }
              cor_withN(runif(100), runif(100))
                 [1] "N = 100"
                       cor   N
                cor 0.1718225 100
```

but we often want value of cor separate from N,so we can write  the results as 2 files (cor file and N file) any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A terrible hack I must admit, but this does the trick:

```
cor_withN = function(...) {
   cor_obj = cor.test(...)
   print(sprintf("N = %s", cor_obj$parameter + 2))
   return(data.frame(cor = cor_obj$estimate, N = cor_obj$parameter + 2))
 }
cor_withN(runif(100), runif(100))
[1] "N = 100"
          cor   N
cor 0.1718225 100
```

The advantage of the above function is that it determines `N` regardless of which input you feed to `cor.test`: one `data.frame`, two vectors, etc.

But when you calculate the correlation, you can just get N from the input argument:

```
N = length(runif(100))
```

Comment: Just replace `cor` by `cor_withN`.